# how to solve z-index of webview control in XAML in metro style app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i create item details page divided to 3 rows ,i put scrollviewer in row no 2, scrollview contains  two pargraph and webview ,when i scroll the page ,webview appear on the row no 3 means that it ovelay row no 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView suffers from an [airspace](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/23a235a2-b0a3-4161-bc74-c42289c61264) issue. as it is not hosted in the same render target as the rest of the app, but rather in a separate HWND window. There is currently no good way around that other than manually resizing the WebView to make it fit in your boundaries.

You can use a [WebViewBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush.aspx) instead of the WebView, but that has a set of limitations of its own - basically it is just a non-interactive brush. Its documentation shows how you can use it to temporarily show the non-interactive page while some other content is rendered on top of it.

Comment: ..which is •extra• fun when you are trying to put it inside a ScrollViewer.  Hint: save your time and give up now

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you only want to display a Web page, WebViewBrush may be able to be used.

official sample code: [XAML WebView control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-ada6c1a1/view/SourceCode#content) - ScenarioInput4.ComboBox1_DropDownOpened()